# Sympy and Math Python Error That I don't get

Tags: python, sympy

I have a simple program:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy.core import parameters
import math;

x = Symbol('x')
y = Symbol('y')

V = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)

f = lambdify([x, y], V)

print(f(1.0, 1.0))
```

and I get this error which I don't get:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nmadhu/Desktop/Nandana_Repo/Science_Fair/9th_Grade/Code/Yukawa/Potetial0Graph_Yukawa.py", line 17, in <module>
    V = math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sympy-1.8-py3.9.egg/sympy/core/expr.py", line 358, in __float__
    raise TypeError("can't convert expression to float")
TypeError: can't convert expression to float
```

Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Comment: `math` functions expect numbers, floats.  You are trying to give it `symbols`.  Why are you using `math`?  Why not stick with `sympy`?  It can do sqrt.

Comment: Use the `sympy.sqrt` function rather than `math.sqrt`.